# VB net table adapter insert query not working

Tags: vb.net, insert-into

Update query on the same table (table adapter) works just fine but in a an insert query i get this error:

Command parameter[2] " data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow.

This is the query from the tableadapter:

```
INSERT INTO CurrencyRate(CurrencyRateID, CurrencyCode, ValidFromDate, ValidToDate, EnteredBy, Rate, DeptID, ExportMarker) VALUES        (?, ?, '9/6/2015', '12/31/2099', 1, ?, 1, 1)
```

This is the (part)code from the form:

```
If currencyAttribute <> "USD" Then
                Try
                    'MsgBox("insert into = " & NewPK & " / " & currencyAttribute & " / " & frDate & " / " & toDate & " / " & rateAttribute)
                    scalarQueriesTableAdapter.InsertIntoCurrency(NewPK, currencyAttribute, rateAttribute)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("Error occured when inserting new line into currencyrate table." _
                          & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                          & ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
```

Tried my best to diagnose which parameter cant' get in. All parameters seem fine ... ?!?!?!???

Comment: So what are the values of `NewPK, currencyAttribute, rateAttribute`? What are the types in database?

Comment: Also, what rdbms are you using?

Comment: I'm a noob so bare with me :).

rdbms if I understand correctly is Sybase 12 connected.

NewPK is last extracted PK from the table + 1, currencyAttribute is a 3 letter string and rate is a Double. 
I tried all of these manually by removing ? from table adapter query and entering manually the data and i get an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot convert '6/9/2015' to a timestamp